# Pandas : Get count of rows which satisfy certain conditions , for each row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to implement the following paper : [Melville invoice to cash](http://www.prem-melville.com/publications/equitant-kdd08.pdf)

Page 3 of the paper has list of features used.

The dataset will have one entry for an invoice and each entry will have the following fields :

```
creation_date  payment_date   customer_id
 2016-01-01     2016-01-03       0
 2016-01-02     2016-01-02       1
 2016-01-02     2016-01-02       1 
 2016-01-04     2016-01-05       0
```

Now , for each invoice , I need to calculate the number invoices that have been paid prior to the creation date of the current invoice , for that customer.
So,the result will be :

```
 creation_date  payment_date   customer_id    no_invoice_paid 
 2016-01-01     2016-01-03       0                  0
 2016-01-02     2016-01-02       1                  0 
 2016-01-02     2016-01-02       1                  0 
 2016-01-04     2016-01-05       0                  1
```

I came up with a naive solution :

```
data_customer  = data.groupby(by='customer_id')

final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for group , group_data in data_customer:
    group_data = group_data.assign(no_invoice_before=count_paid_invoice)
    final_df  = final_df.append(group_data)
```

The count paid invoice function is as follows :

```
def count_paid_invoice(group_data):
    for index , row in group_data.iterrows() :
     group_data.iloc[index,13] = group_data[(group_data['creation_date'] < row['creation_date']) & (group_data['payment_date'] < row['creation_date'])].shape[0]
    return group_data.iloc[:,13]
```

But this is very slow. Is there a way this can be done more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, this should give you the desired result.

```
df['no_invoice_paid '] = df.apply(lambda row:
    df[(df.customer_id == row['customer_id']) &
       (df.payment_date < row['creation_date'])].shape[0] ,axis=1)
```

Or even shorter:

```
df['no_invoice_paid '] = df.apply(lambda row:
    ((df.customer_id == row['customer_id']) &
     (df.payment_date < row['creation_date'])).sum(), axis=1)
```

Another approach (similar to the one from Spandan):

```
df = df.sort_values(['customer_id', 'payment_date'])
payment_lookup  = df.groupby(('customer_id', 'payment_date')).count().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()

from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(maxsize=1024)
def get_customer_payments(customer_id):
    return payment_lookup.loc[customer_id]

@lru_cache(maxsize=1024)
def lookup_payments(customer_id, payment_date):
    customer_payments = get_customer_payments(customer_id)
    payments_before_current = customer_payments[customer_payments.index <
                                                payment_date]
    try:
        return payments_before_current.values[-1][0]
    except IndexError:
        return 0


df['no_invoice_paid'] = df.apply(lambda row:
                                 lookup_payments(row['customer_id'],
                                                 row['creation_date']), axis=1)
```

I didn't test the performance. Let me know if works.

Comment: This does give me the desired result , but the performance side is still very similar to what I originally had. Takes more than an hour for 500k rows .

Comment: @SyedSaad I just added another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `cumsum()` and `pd.concat`.

Try following :

```
data['is_invoice_paid'] = 1  # Creating a dummy variable
count_invoice = data.groupby('customer_id')['is_invoice_paid'].cumsum()
count_invoice.name = 'no_invoice_paid'
final_df = pd.concat([data,count_invoice],axis=1)
final_df['no_invoice_paid'] = final_df['no_invoice_paid'] - 1  # to set the count correct
final_df = final_df.drop('is_invoice_paid',axis=1)
```

I am assuming 2 things here :

1. Your payment date cannot be before creation date.
2. Payment date for every customer is sorted.

Comment: Hi Spandan , your solution doesn't consider the essential condition that payment date of invoice should be less than the creation date of the current invoice.